# How to return values of variables from a function in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, variables

```
import random
import time

#universal variables
attack = 1
defend = 2
heal = 3
v = False

player_health = 0
player_damage = 0
player_heal = 0
player_block = 0

ai_health = 0
ai_damage = 0
ai_heal = 0
ai_block = 0

#player classes in the form of dictionaries
sniper = {}
sniper["health"] = 50
sniper["damage"] = random.randint(20,40)
sniper["heal"] = random.randint(2,10)
sniper["block"] = 5

tank = {}
tank["health"] = 200
tank["damage"] = random.randint(2,8)
tank["heal"] = random.randint(5,20)
tank["block"] = 20

def start():
    print "lets play"
    while clas():
        pass
    while game():
        pass
    win()

#get the class of the player
def clas():
    while True:
        Class = raw_input("choose a class:\nsniper = 1\ntank =2\n") #change as stats are added
        try:
            Class = int(Class)
            if Class in (1,2): #change as stats are added
                    Class1 = random.randint(1,2)

    #get the class' stats for the player
                    if Class == 1:
                        player_health = sniper["health"]
                        player_damage = sniper["damage"]
                        player_heal = sniper["heal"]
                        player_block = sniper["block"]

                    if Class == 2:
                        player_health = tank["health"]
                        player_damage = tank["damage"]
                        player_heal = tank["heal"]
                        player_block = tank["block"]

                    #get the class' stats for the ai
                    if Class1 == 1:
                        ai_health = sniper["health"]
                        ai_damage = sniper["damage"]
                        ai_heal = sniper["heal"]
                        ai_block = sniper["block"]

                    if Class1 == 2:
                        ai_health = tank["health"]
                        ai_damage = tank["damage"]
                        ai_heal = tank["heal"]
                        ai_block = tank["block"]
                    break
        except ValueError:
            pass
        print "Oops! I didn't understand that. Please enter a valid number"
```

In the above code, there is a function called clas(). In that function, there are 8 variables about the player and ai stats. I want those variables to copy to the variables at lines 10-18, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: You can add blocks of code by indenting it with four spaces.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If it's telling you that you're trying to add too much code... **then reduce it to the minimal example necessary** to illustrate your point.

Comment: thanks! i haven't been on stack overflow in a while so i forgot

Comment: Using `return` is a good way to return values to the calling code. In Python, any number of values can be returned in a single return statement.

Comment: how would you use return to get the values of the variables in this case?

Comment: @Telekey You need to study the language more. Stack Overflow isn't the place to try to learn the basic semantics of function calls and variable scope.

Comment: You can use `return player_health, player_damage, player_heal, player_block` to return a `tuple` of values. In the long run you might want to use object-oriented design and use a class for the character attributes.

Comment: FWIW, you could make your code simpler & shorter if you used dictionaries for your player and AI instead of those 8 separate variables. Then you could just use the `.copy` method to copy the data from `sniper` or `tank`. Or, as Matthias suggests, you could create a custom class to hold the attributes; a class could also hold functions that operate on those attributes. But at this stage, just using dicts is probably simpler.

Answer (score 0):

In general to copy value of any variable use `copy.deepcopy` function:

```
from copy import deepcopy

z = 1
x = {'a': {'z': 12}}

def copy_args(z, x):
    copy_z = deepcopy(z)
    copy_x = deepcopy(x)
    return copy_z, copy_x

copy_z, copy_x = copy_args(z, x)
print(copy_z, copy_x)
```

See more on [python-course deepcopy article](http://www.python-course.eu/deep_copy.php) and [python copy module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)

Good Luck